# on Submit validation

Tags: jquery

i need help in  submit a form in which i have check email is existing in the drop down ,while submit the form it show the alert message but also submit the form ,when no alert message shown then only form need to submit

```
$(document).on('click', '#Records', function (event) {
    $("#dropval select option:selected").each(function () {
        var z = $(this).val();
        //alert(z);
        if(z != 'email') {
            alert('please select Email');
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    });
});
});

   <form  name="search" method="post" action="sample1.php" >
  <div id="dropval">

  <select name="select3[1]" class="mySelects" >
  <option value="None"  selected > None</option>
  <option value="email" >email</option>
  <option value="firstname" >firstname</option>
  <option value="lastname" >lastname</option>
  <option value="mobile" >mobile</option>
  </select>
  <select name="select3[2]" class="mySelects" >
  <option value="None" selected > None</option>
  <option value="email" >email</option>
  <option value="firstname" >firstname</option>
  <option value="lastname" >lastname</option>
  <option value="mobile" >mobile</option>
  </select>
  <select name="select3[3]" class="mySelects" >
  <option value="None" selected > None</option>
  <option value="email" >email</option>
  <option value="firstname" >firstname</option>
  <option value="lastname" >lastname</option>
  <option value="mobile" >mobile</option>
  </select>
  <select name="select3[4]" class="mySelect" >
  <option value="None"  selected> None</option>
  <option value="email" >email</option>
  <option value="firstname" >firstname</option>
  <option value="lastname" >lastname</option>
  <option value="mobile" >mobile</option>
  </select>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" id="Records">
  </form>
```

Comment: Could you also give us your HTML?

Also, put `e.preventDefault()` at the beginning of the handler. Plus, you are never giving 'e' to the handler, so it doesn't exist.

Comment: The answer probably was event.preventDefault() though. Chris Ledet had it just before I did. He should get kudos.

Comment: after adding event.preventDefault(); after select email ,still im getting email alert and form is not getting submitted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#formy').bind('submit', function(event){
    var success = false;

    $("#dropval select option:selected").each(function () {
        var z = $(this).val();
        if(z == 'email') {
            success = true;
        }
    });

    return success;
});
```

You were returning in the loop, this won't do anything to the submit.

Comment: Thanks But Still after selecting email form is not getting submitted

Comment: Would be a lot cleaner just to return success of course. But lets see about fixing this for you ;).

Comment: Thanks Mosselman, i tried adding alert message , its displaying four times    $('#formy').bind('submit', function(event){
    var success = false;
i have to add alert message to select the email
    $("#dropval select option:selected").each(function () {
        var z = $(this).val();
        if(z == 'email') {
            success = true;
        }else
        {
            alert('please select email');
            success = false;
        }
        });
    
       return success;
      });

Answer (score 0):

If you call your function on the form submit instead of the button click it should solve your issue as returning false here stops the form from submitting.

```
$('#formName').on('submit', function() {
    //Validation code here
    if(valid == false) {
        return false; //Stops the form from submitting
    } else {
        return true; //Allows the form to submit
    }
});
```

Comment: Not an answer to the question. I is a suggestion, but hardly worth 'answering'.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', '#Records', function(event) {
    $("#dropval select option:selected").each( function (){
        var z = $(this).val();
        //alert(z);
        if(z!='email'){
            alert('please select Email');
            event.preventDefault(); // 'e' was undefined before, as you named your variable 'event'. This would have been causing an error and code below would not have been executed - as a result, your form would have been submitted after the alert.
            return false;
        }
     });
});
```

As a side note, binding events to the `document` such as `click` is inefficient. Try to bind it to a closer parent.

Comment: I like, clean. I suspect that return false should work, but I have seen it not do the trick once or twice. Maybe throw in that event.preventDefault() just to be sure?

Comment: actually, you're right. In this instance I don't think `return false` would work - as it's returning to the `each()` callback.

Comment: I wouldn't go as far as saying that I was right though ;). I hadn't caught that. I just know that I have bad experience with 'just' returning false.